# Setup Apache Server With Django (hopefully also with git)

Tags: python, django, apache, web-deployment

I've created a website and would now like to host it. I already have an apache server setup

[image: Apache Server Home]

I literally have no clue what to do and how to go further, The tutorials online haven't been much help too, since I'm still utterly lost, I've figured out there is a command shell but don't really know how to use it even when the code is right in front of me. If someone could steer me in the right direction that would be a huge help. I have looked at multiple different tutorials, videos and articles, and still have no idea what to do. I'd also love if someone could show me how to use the server with git so when I want to update the server, I can simply by pushing (similar to Heroku I think)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to install mod_wsgi library in the apache folder and create an app.wsgi file.

Please thoroughly refer this article - https://www.codementor.io/@aswinmurugesh/deploying-a-django-application-in-windows-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-uhl2xq09e

Comment: Where do I run the commands? I tried running them in the command shell but one of them has a y/n question, and it automatically chooses abort

Comment: Can you show that... Also run on Admin cmd(Right click on cmd icon --> run as admin)